# dynamic filled div not scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm new to web world so i'm developing a simple site in order to learn a little bit, so i have this javascript function that fill a div:

```
    function printdiv(url, img, title, price, city, position) {
        var redirect = url; 
        function loadScript() {
            window.location.href = redirect;
        }
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.height = "25vh";
        //div.style.overflowY = "auto";
        div.style.width = "600px";
        div.style.background = "#F2F2F2";
        div.style.border = "3px dashed #666633";
        div.classList.add('position_'+position);
        div.style.position = "fixed";
        div.style.top = position+"%";
        div.style.left = "25%";
        div.onclick = loadScript;
        div.innerHTML += '<img src="'+ img +'" width="200" height="137"/>';
        div.innerHTML += '<h3 style="float: right; position: absolute; top:0; right:0; margin-top: 1px; ">' + title +'</h3>';
        div.innerHTML += '<h4 style="float: right; position: absolute; top:0; right:0; margin-top: 85px; padding-right:55px;">PREZZO:'+ ' ' + price +'</h4>';
        div.innerHTML += '<h4 style="float: right; position: absolute; top:0; right:0; margin-top: 110px; padding-right:50px;">CITTÀ:'+ ' ' + city +'</h4>';
        document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
        document.getElementById('main').setAttribute("style","height :"+ 30 + position +"px");
    }
```

The above code fill the follow div:

```
<div class="main" id="main"></div>
```

i execute this function in a loop in order to add multiple div inside the "main" div with different position, but even though the scrollbar is visible it doesn't work.
If i add a css background to the div the scrollbar scroll correctly the background but all the dynamic added div inside the "main" div remain locked and go down in to the page.

Before to write this question i've already tried multiple similar topic to stackoverflow but nothing worked, so could you please give me an help ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your DIV to be overflowed by scrolling you have to set the #main div to be positioned as relative and don't set the child DIV to fixed.

```
function printdiv(url, img, title, price, city, position) {
    var redirect = url; 
    function loadScript() {
        window.location.href = redirect;
    }
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.height = "25vh";
    //div.style.overflowY = "auto";
    div.style.width = "600px";
    div.style.background = "#F2F2F2";
    div.style.border = "3px dashed #666633";
    div.classList.add('position_'+position);
    div.style.top = position+"%";
    div.style.left = "25%";
    div.onclick = loadScript;
    div.innerHTML += '<img src="'+ img +'" width="200" height="137"/>';
    div.innerHTML += '<h3 style="float: right; position: absolute; top:0; right:0; margin-top: 1px; ">' + title +'</h3>';
    div.innerHTML += '<h4 style="float: right; position: absolute; top:0; right:0; margin-top: 85px; padding-right:55px;">PREZZO:'+ ' ' + price +'</h4>';
    div.innerHTML += '<h4 style="float: right; position: absolute; top:0; right:0; margin-top: 110px; padding-right:50px;">CITTÀ:'+ ' ' + city +'</h4>';
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
    document.getElementById('main').setAttribute("style","height :"+ 30 + position +"px;position:relative;overflow:scroll;");
}
```